# Make an Android library embedding JNI : No implementation found

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface

My goal is to build an Android Library embedding the *[superpowered](http://superpowered.com/)* library. This library provide Android static libraries (.a files) and C++ headers.

I already created a module (with type Android Library) so it use the *superpowered* library :

- I configured graddle so it allows NDK / JNI
- I included .a files and headers related to *superpowered*
- In my Java class, I set the native method, which maps to cpp methods.

To create this module I highly used the [Cross Example](https://github.com/superpoweredSDK/Low-Latency-Android-Audio-iOS-Audio-Engine/tree/master/Android/CrossExample) sample provided by *superpowered*. It is an Android App, and for now as a first step, I just want to break it into 2 parts : an App and an Android library.

In my Android application, I added dependency to this module. But when I call a method which calls a JNI method, I obtain this error :

```
E/art: No implementation found for void
  com.example.mylib.MyDSP.onPlayPause(boolean) 
  (tried Java_com_example_mylib_MyDSP_onPlayPause 
  and Java_com_example_mylib_MyDSP_onPlayPause__Z)
```

Any ideas on why it does not work ?

---

**Sources :**

---

In Android lib :

My java class `MyDSP` ([MyDSP.java](https://github.com/DelattreAdixon/Superpowered-Android-Lib/blob/master/mylib/src/main/java/com/example/mylib/MyDSP.java)) :

```
package com.example.mylib;

public class MyDSP {

    public  void CallJniCppMethod() {

        this.onPlayPause(true);
    }

    private native void onPlayPause(boolean play);

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("SuperpoweredExample");
    }

}
```

In the cpp file : SuperpoweredExample.cpp ([SuperpoweredExample.cpp](https://github.com/DelattreAdixon/Superpowered-Android-Lib/blob/master/mylib/src/main/jni/SuperpoweredExample.cpp))

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT void Java_com_example_mylib_MyDSP_onPlayPause(JNIEnv * __unused javaEnvironment, jobject __unused obj, jboolean play) {
    //example->onPlayPause(play);

    // We do nothing, but it's OK,
    // Just want to see if the JNI call does not throw exception
}
```

The h file : SuperpoweredExample.h ([SuperpoweredExample.h](https://github.com/DelattreAdixon/Superpowered-Android-Lib/blob/master/mylib/src/main/jni/SuperpoweredExample.h)
)

```
void onPlayPause(bool play);
```

The graddle configuration for the lib ([build.gradle](https://github.com/DelattreAdixon/Superpowered-Android-Lib/blob/master/mylib/build.gradle)) :

apply plugin: 'com.android.model.library'

```
Properties properties = new Properties()
properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
def superpowered_sdk_path = properties.getProperty('superpowered.dir')

model {
    repositories {
        libs(PrebuiltLibraries) {
            superpowered { // this is where you declare the "superpowered" static library
                headers.srcDir "${superpowered_sdk_path}"
                binaries.withType(StaticLibraryBinary) { // attaching library files to each platform
                    def platformName = targetPlatform.getName()
                    if (platformName == "armeabi-v7a") {
                        staticLibraryFile = file("${superpowered_sdk_path}/libSuperpoweredAndroidARM.a")
                    } else if (platformName == "arm64-v8a") {
                        staticLibraryFile = file("${superpowered_sdk_path}/libSuperpoweredAndroidARM64.a")
                    } else if (platformName == "x86") {
                        staticLibraryFile = file("${superpowered_sdk_path}/libSuperpoweredAndroidX86.a")
                    } else if (platformName == "x86_64") {
                        staticLibraryFile = file("${superpowered_sdk_path}/libSuperpoweredAndroidX86_64.a")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 24
        buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 21 // more than 95% of all active Android devices
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 21
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }

    }


    android.ndk { // your application's native layer parameters
        moduleName = "SuperpoweredExample"
        platformVersion = 21
        stl = "c++_static"
        CFlags.addAll(["-O3", "-fsigned-char"]) // full optimization, char data type is signed
        cppFlags.addAll(["-fsigned-char", "-I${superpowered_sdk_path}".toString()])
        ldLibs.addAll(["log", "android", "OpenSLES"]) // load these libraries: log, android, OpenSL ES (for audio)
        abiFilters.addAll(["armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86", "x86_64"]) // these platforms cover 99% percent of all Android devices
    }

    android.sources.main.jni {
        source {
            srcDir "jni"
            srcDir "${superpowered_sdk_path}/AndroidIO"
        }
        dependencies {
            library "superpowered" linkage "static" // this is where you attach the "superpowered" static library to your app
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
}
```

**Note :**

All my sources are available on Github : https://github.com/DelattreAdixon/Superpowered-Android-Lib

In order to build it/run it, you will have to change le `local.properties` content so it match you ndk/sdk/superpowered paths.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `experimental gradle`, It take care of create cpp file, create functions inside this files and linked it with your java class.

Try deleting cpp file, click on `private native void onPlayPause(boolean play)` to mark it and them alt+intro, It show a dialog to auto-generate cpp file and the function inside it.

Comment: Following your instructions, it generates a .c file (without .h), with the metho (which I kept empty). And when running the App, it works correctly (no exception thrown). 
Now, as I would like a .cpp file (my method will contain cpp instructions), I tried to rename the generated file with a .cpp extension. And this now lead to the same exception : No implementation found.

Comment: You forgot this flag to built c++ files cFlags "-std=c++11 -fexceptions"